# Unable to install YO on ubuntu using terminal

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, yo

I am trying to install yo on my ubuntu machine using the following command

```
sudo npm install -g yo
```

but it threw me the  an error as follows

[image]

Not sure how to deal with this error

Comment: Which version of node do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using an old version of node.

I would recommend you to use [`Node Version Manager`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

1. [Install NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) - `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.23.0/install.sh | bash`
2. Install latest node version - `nvm install 0.10.35`
3. Remove your old `node_modules`
4. Try to install the package again `npm install -g yo`

Comment: @Dev Did you install it with `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.23.0/install.sh | bash
` ?

Comment: I have now installed nvm but the same error again for yo

Comment: @Dev could you try to reinstall your global node modules? For this, you'd have to physically remove them (or move to a backup folder)